# How should I automatically change my .zshrc for different OS'?

Tags: linux, macos, zsh

I am currently storing most of my dotfiles in a git repository to make keeping them in sync across all my computers easier.  I've just recently acquired a Macbook so now have to have all my dotfiles supporting the differences between Linux and Darwin.  The first incompatability that I have encountered is colour coding `ls`, in Linux this is the flag `--color=auto` and for Darwin it is `-G`.

My first attempt at making my `.zshrc` portable is to do the following:

```
case `uname` in
  Darwin)
    alias ls='ls -FG'
    ;;
  Linux)
    alias ls='ls -F --color=auto'
    ;;
esac
```

Once I find a few more things to change I'll probably pull the computer specific stuff out to separate files to keep it a bit cleaner.  What I'm mainly wondering is if there is a better way to do this other than using `` `uname` `` to determine which stuff to run.

Answer (score 4):

I used to use this mechanism:

```
envfile="$HOME/.bash/os.`uname`.sh"
if [ -r $envfile ]; then
    . $envfile
fi
envfile="$HOME/.bash/host.`uname -n`.sh"
if [ -r $envfile ]; then
    . $envfile
fi
```

Then I could rsync the .bash directory around to each machine as needed to keep all up to date.